# How do i do arithmetic for all elements of a list

Tags: python-2.7, list

I need to find the biggest factor of the number 600851475143

so in order for doing that i want to find all primes smaller that this number

```
number = input("enter max number:")
def findprime (number):
    prime = [1,2]
    for i in range (2,number):
        if(i%)
```

how do i preform arithmetic's for all numbers in a list?

Comment: what do you mean by "preform arithmetic's for all numbers in a list"? you wanna test if i is a factor? number%i == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the largest factor, find the smallest one and divide. And you only need to check up to  the sqrt of the number:

```
factor = 0
for i in range (2, int(number**0.5) + 1):
    if number%i == 0:
        factor = i
        break
if factor: print(number/factor)
else: print number, 'is prime'
```